# find string in file on server and replace it

Tags: php, linux

I made a certain script in `.php` that will find all appearances of certain code( in my case javascript code with `<script>` tags), and replace it with something else, on live server.

Something like `grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"` .

My question is : how to run a `.php` script on server that will search all files on that server for certain string and then replace it with other string.

On my desktop I've coded this and it worked : 
`

```
<?php
$what = <<<EOD
<script>bla bla string</script>
EOD;
$with=" ";
$path_to_file = '/Users/Michael/Desktop/results-prod.txt';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace($what,$with,$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
?>
```

and now I need something for live server and all files(more than 1 and all using different paths).

Thanks,
Michael!

Comment: wouldn't that be as easy as changing `$path_to_file` to fit the path that exists on the server?

Comment: there are 90 files that require this change. I'd like to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: I would use `sed` for this if you have root permission ...

Comment: Would using `scandir()` help? You can just foreach through its results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$FIND = "your mom";
$REPLACE = "your dad";

$DIR= "/path/to/dir";
$FILES = scandir($DIR);
foreach($FILES as $FILE){
    if($FILE == "." || $FILE == "..") continue;
    $PATH = "$DIR/$FILE";
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($PATH);
    $file_contents = str_replace($FIND,$REPLACE,$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($PATH,$file_contents);
}
```

Comment: but this  works only if i give it a direct path to folder where file is located. I've tried with relative path like `/home/www/` and it didn't work, but with `/home/www/site/folder/michael` it did.

Comment: `/home/www/` isn't a relative path. more than likely, you just didn't have permissions to edit that folder with PHP.

Comment: Hi, I think that you'r script is not entering the folders. It's just searching for files in the path we give it. I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

From a command prompt in linux you could simply do this:

```
find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/stringToReplace/replacementString/g'
```

More elaborated

```
find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i s/'<script>[^)]*<\/script>'/'<script>Stuff To Replace With<\/script>'/g
```

Remember with `sed` as in anything you're using regular expressions with ... You'll need to escape certain characters ...

Comment: and how would i load big javascript inside stringToReplace inside sed ? can i assign it to a variable like in my case from desktop and then call it in sed?

Comment: basically let me put it like this : i am trying to put this string "`<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}</script>`" inside variable so i can use it in sed like :` find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/VARIABLE_GOES_HERE/replaced_with_this/g' `

Comment: I updated my answer  --  Remember with `sed`, you'll need to escape characters it doesn't like  ..  `/` and `'` are common ones